# Show that a progression converges and assess the limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$a_{n} = \sqrt{9n^2+2n+1} -3n$

I tried to simplify the term to show that the limit is $\frac{1}{3}$ with the binominal formula for example $\sqrt{9n^2+6n+1-4n} = \sqrt{(3n+1)^2-4n}$ or playing around with the $9n^2$ but because of the $-3n$ after the radical, it never becomes easier as it was... Running out of ideas now and would aprreciate a new idea how to solve this.

Comment: If you see $\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B}$, multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{B}}{\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{B}}$ is often the best thing to try.

Comment: Ah. Assess. So the question title is a command to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $a_{n} = \sqrt{9n^2+2n+1} -3n = \frac{(\sqrt{9n^2+2n+1} -3n)(\sqrt{9n^2+2n+1} +3n)}{\sqrt{9n^2+2n+1} + 3n}=\frac{(2n+1)}{\sqrt{9n^2+2n+1} + 3n} = \frac{(2+\frac{1}{n})}{\sqrt{9+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}} + 3}$

Comment: I already got that far but I still couldnt see how that would make it any easier... anyway I just looked up the last lecture and noticed that we said that if u have two polynomials N-degree p(x) and M-degree q(x). And we proofed that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{p(n)}{q(n)}} = \frac{a_N}{b_M}$ for $M = N$ I hope i see that right but if I use this there would be something left like $\frac{2}{3+3} \Leftrightarrow \frac{2}{6} \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{3}$. Can i do that like this?

Comment: I editted my answer and moved it a step forward. Can you see it now? If you can't ask again. :)

Comment: ah i think i got it. if u go $n \rightarrow \infty$ it becomes $\frac{2+0}{\sqrt{9+0+0}+3} \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: There you go! Good Luck! :)

Comment: could u help me with anohther one. $a_n = \frac{n^3+\sqrt{n}}{2(n+1)(n^2-2)}$ I am trying since i finished the first one and i think i need a hint again :/

Comment: @Weenzeal : I think you should make that another question.